# Cannot make chromium to push button (python)

Tags: web-scraping

Basicaly, here is my code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url='https://www.gpsies.com/map.do;jsessionid=9B6652B60485A9F1C92C333F683807D7.fe3?fileId=iovpsivunvmipazp'
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn btn-default').click()
```

on that website, there is a button "download" and here is the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.1.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.1.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "D:/PYTHON/directions/src/tools_set/gpsies_scrap.py", line 34, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn btn-default').click()
  File "C:\Users\ALM\Anaconda3\envs\dir2\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 564, in find_element_by_class_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
  File "C:\Users\ALM\Anaconda3\envs\dir2\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\ALM\Anaconda3\envs\dir2\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\ALM\Anaconda3\envs\dir2\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".btn btn-default"}
  (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.132)
```

Could somebody help ?

Also. I do not want chromium to open new window, instead work in background. Is it possible ?

Comment: It's not able to find the button you're trying to click.

Comment: I made it to work. 
This is the line:
```
button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#downloadForm > div:nth-child(3) > div.panel-body > div:nth-child(2) > div > button.btn')
button.click()
```